# Yii странное поведение CDbCriteria с условием IN()

Tags: yii

### Нерабочий пример

```
$ids = implode(',', $likely_products_ids);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "t.id IN (:likely_ids)";
$criteria->params = ['likely_ids'=>$ids];

$products = Products::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

### Результат

Возвращает только 1 значение, id которого - первый элемент из $ids
Запрос в этом случае такой:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` `t` WHERE t.id IN (:likely_ids)

:likely_ids 128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137
```

### Рабочий, небезопасный пример

```
$ids = implode(',', $likely_products_ids);

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "t.id IN ({$ids})";

$products = Products::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

### Результат

Возвращает все запошеные записи.
Запрос в этом случае такой:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` `t` WHERE t.id IN (128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137)
```

Comment: но это же логично.. один параметр биндиться, соответственно один подставляется.. для `IN` видимо нужен бинд чрез цикл

Comment: но ведь запрос одинаковый в результате

Comment: Ну где же... `:likely_ids 128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137` и `:ycp0   128
:ycp1   129
:ycp2   130
:ycp3   131
:ycp4   132
:ycp5   133
:ycp6   134
:ycp7   135
:ycp8   136
:ycp9   137`  явно не одинаковы по количеству параметров `:bind`

Comment: я про нерабочий пример и рабочий, но небезопасный

Comment: Но это да.......но  `не сразу сообразил такое поведение.` ----> я и говорю, а какого поведения ожидали от первого случая? Оно вполне логичное и закономерное.........Собственно, а вопрос в чем?))

Comment: непонятно как биндятся параметры запроса :( почему обязательно должно быть бинд = 1 значение, тем более что никаких ковычек и прочего не добавляется

Comment: Сколько параметров вставляете столько и биндите. 1 к 1. Это основы работы с `pdo/mysqli` ..... Нужно 100 значений пробиндить - ставьте в соответствие 100 значений, которым они соответствуют....Машина же не может знать, что вы вставляете много значений, ей надо сказать об этом.. А как? Показать это через  бинды.  http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php ........ http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  ....... ожидается что один `:bind` соответствует одному значению, чтоб корректно обработать его как int или str или еще как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Правильный вариант поиска

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('t.id', $likely_products_ids);

$products = Products::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

### Результат

Возвращает все запощеные записи.
Запрос в этом случае такой:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` `t` WHERE t.id IN (:ycp0, :ycp1, :ycp2, :ycp3, :ycp4, :ycp5, :ycp6, :ycp7, :ycp8, :ycp9)

:ycp0   128
:ycp1   129
:ycp2   130
:ycp3   131
:ycp4   132
:ycp5   133
:ycp6   134
:ycp7   135
:ycp8   136
:ycp9   137
```

Может кому пригодится, не сразу сообразил такое поведение.